# Screen Navigation in android

Tags: android, android-intent

I think this may be a chilly question also i didn't have that much depth knowledge in android so only posting this question.Consider i have 2 screens screen A and screen B.In A i have one spinner,in that if user selects any 1 value from spinner i am redirecting to B.This working properly.But when user selects any value from spinner from A its give a illusion that it is going to screen A and then it goes to screen B.I don't know this can't be changed.

My code:

```
    s1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() 
              {
                  public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> s2, View arg1,
                            int pos, long id) 
                  {               
                      if(!s1.getItemAtPosition(pos).equals("No recurrence"))
                      {

 Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),IncomeStartDate.class);
                      startActivityForResult(intent, 1);    
    }
    }
    }
```

Please post ur ideas..Thanks in advance..

Comment: have you included the code that actually does the redirection to B?

Comment: sorry sam..now u can c my post..

Comment: please further describe what you want to happen and what is happening.